# Is the pseudomenon a statement?

Tags: logic, paradoxes

I'm asking this because I'm teaching a class on paradoxes for kids, and I realized I have no idea what the answer to this question is.  It is a research question in the pedagogical sense, I suppose.

I'm referring to the famous "liar's paradox," which in one form asserts: "This sentence is false."  According to the logic definition of the word "statement," does it qualify as a statement?

The easy answer would be that it does not because it does not have a distinct truth value.  But the reason why it does not have a distinct truth value is quite different from the reason one would give in most examples of non-statements.  Moreover, if it is not a statement, then would we say that the continuum hypothesis is also not a statement?  And taking that a step further, can we confidently call any conjecture a statement unless it has been established as not being independent of the axiomatic structure in use?  Lastly, does the status as statement depend on the axiomatic structure?  For example, is the axiom of choice a non-statement in ZF, but a statement in ZFC?

I do not work in logic so please forgive my naivete.  As I said I'm asking for the benefit of some young students who I'd like to have a better answer for.

Comment: It seems that your question is more of a philosophical than mathematical nature. And „Philosophers do not agree on what a sentence is, but they disagree more about what a statement is, and they disagree even more about what a proposition is.”- see http://www.iep.utm.edu/par-liar/#SH2b E.g. in paraconsistent logic you cannot use a definition that a statement does have a distinct truth value. Maybe you should try at http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Todd: This is not a particularly badly written question. If you are going to refer the OP to MSE, why not migrate it instead? (and save me the trouble of copy-pasting my answer if and when that time comes...)

Comment: Asaf made explicit his assumption of working in classical first-order logic. Certainly, it is not the only reasonable way of analyzing the liar paradox.

Comment: @Waldemar: Oh, of course not. But it seemed natural, given the other examples of "non-statements" given in the question.

Comment: Thanks for migrating it.  I did feel like Mathoverflow may not be the right place, but, well it's the only place I've been posting stuff lately and I don't usually ask questions about stuff I have to teach..  Anyway, yeah I agree with the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will add a point which sound important  for this discussion.

There is only one strict definition of "statement" - the definition in mathematical logic, where a statement is defined in terms of *syntax* of a formal language (say, of 1st order predicate logic). This definition is correlated with that formal language, and cannot help answer your question about English which is another language. What would help is a definition in *semantic* terms. Logicians use "interpretations" which are functions in their "semantics", and this permit to talk about semantics strictly. Here is a "definition" (or "criterium") of "statement" (or, of "qualifying as statement") in natural languages:

A statement is a sentence $S$, for which there exists at least one interpretation such, that the question "Is $S$ true?" can be answered "Yes" or "No" in this interpretation.

A paradox has no interpretations as explained by Asaf Karagila. Therefore, it is not a statement.
The continuum hypothesis has at least one such interpretation. Therefore, it is a statement.

To fully comply with the "definition", I should have said above "the continuum hypothesis formulated (phrazed) in English, or any other natural language". Probably, I could improve the wording of the "definition", so that it is "works" both for natural languages and mathematical formulas, but at this time, this is the best short wording which I could figure.

Comment: This makes more clear the distinction between a statement and its interpretation in a language. However, I do not think we should assume we have such a clear definition of what constitutes a paradox. At the moment I agree with Quine, that it is often a matter of perspective.  Your requirement for "paradox" coincides with Quine's requirement for "antimony," and ignores the "lesser" categorizations (falsidical or veridical).  What distinguishes the antimony is that it contradicts itself, not just some tentative assumption. Perhaps it is an interpretation that can be paradoxical, not a statement.

Comment: My definition explains why the sentence "this sentence is false" is not a statement, while the other sentences analysed here are, but does not explain what is a paradox. Also, it applies to anti-nomy, but not to more subtle categorizations. My answer is specific for classical mathematics where distinction is  made between "meaningful" and "meaningless" (like, "truth values" - "true" and "false"), but not also between various "sense values". In  mathematics, "to be meaningful" is treated synonymously with "to have an interpretation" - either there is an interpretation, or there is not.

Answer (score 9):

You have made the well known confusion between true and provable. (And throughout this answer I will assume we work in classical first-order logic.)

Truth value is given in a particular structure. The continuum hypothesis *has a truth value*, it just can be different in different models of $\sf ZFC$. And in every model of $\sf ZF$ the axiom of choice has a truth value, but in some models it's true and in other it is false.

The fact that a statement is not provable from a particular theory does not preclude it from having a truth value, *in a particular model for the theory*. Two simpler examples are these:

1. $\forall x\forall y(x\cdot y=y\cdot x)$. Is this true in the language of groups?

   Well, first of all the question should be if this is provable, not true. The answer is that it is not provable, since some groups are abelian and others are not.
2. $\exists x\forall y(x\cdot x\cdot x=2\land y\cdot y\cdot y=2\rightarrow x=y)$, namely there is a unique cubic root to $2$. Is this true in the language of fields?

   Again, the question should be if this is provable from the theory of fields, and again the answer would be negative. In $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb C$ there are no such $x$, and three such $x$ respectively; and in $\Bbb R$ there is just one.

Let me digress for a moment, and analyze this mistake. I see it coming mainly from two possible sources:

1. Bad terminology. We sometimes use "true in $T$" as a synonym for "provable from $T$", because the completeness theorem tells us that $T$ proves something if and only if it is true in all the models of $T$. So sometimes we say things like "*$\aleph_1\leq2^{\aleph_0}$ is true in $\sf ZFC$*" when we really mean to say that it is provable.
2. Misunderstanding incompleteness, in particular in foundational theories. Sometimes it is convenient to think that set theory has only one model, the universe of mathematics, rather than considering it equal to other theories like group theory or fields, and then we think that if $\sf ZFC$ can't prove something, then that something has no truth value.

   But this is just misunderstanding that within a given structure (or a universe of mathematics, if you will), a statement has a truth value.

---

**So what about the liar paradox?** If you look at the definition of a well-formed formula, which is really, "a legal statement" you will see that we construct them by induction from the constant symbols and free variables in our language, through the relations and so on.

But this also means that we can draw a tree and deconstruct a statement to its primitive elements. In the liar paradox, "This statement is false", this means that the statement $\varphi$ is in fact $\lnot\varphi$. So when drawing the tree we have just one cycle, which means that this is not a well-formed formula. So it cannot be assigned a truth value in any structure.

But wait, you might say, what about Godel's incompleteness theorem where he wrote a statement "This statement is not provable"? Well, this is not quite accurate. He did something a bit more complicated than that, but this answer is long enough as it is, so I'll stop here and let you digest what I have already written.

Comment: I'm unclear on something.  In your first example, clearly $x$ and $y$ are taken from the domain of elements of some particular group.  As applied to any particular group in group theory, the statement certain is either true or false.  When considered a general property of groups, the "statement" would be false, because of the $\forall$ part.  But, I feel to be a proper statement about group theory, the $\forall$ should apply to a group, not an element of the group.  This just makes the statement a matter of poor grammar, no?

Comment: On the other hand, in the language of arithmetic, there is no confusion in treating variables as numbers.  Doesn't that make all the difference?  Like "$\forall x\forall y: x=y$" is simply false in the language of arithmetic.

Comment: Okay, I think that we may have uncovered a deeper issue here. In classical logic the syntax and semantics are separated. The language of groups is not different between one group and another, and the language of set theory is not different from one model of set theory to the other. There is a language in which we write statements, and there are structures which interpret them. We call the language $\{e,\cdot\}$ (where $e$ is a constant and $\cdot$ is a binary function symbol) the language of groups, and we formulate the group axioms in it; then every structure for this language [...]

Comment: [...] has a particular interpretation of every sentence in the language. Those structure in which the sentences called "group axioms" are true are called "groups". Some of these groups are abelian, and some are not. But the sentence $\forall x\forall y(x\cdot y=y\cdot x)$ is **not** in the context of a particular group, or a particular structure. It is a sentence in the language, and as such it can be provable from the theory "group axioms" or it can be refutable from that theory, or it can be independent from it. In this case, it is independent from it.

Comment: Perhaps before trying to understand paradoxes, statements and independence, it would be wise to pick up a book about first-order logic and understand what is a well-formed formula, and what is the difference between syntax and semantics.

Comment: (Forgive me if I'm being dense) it seems the distinction is in the use of the word "theory."  This effects the domain of the sentence, as in whether the quantifiers apply to the elements or the sets.  "The language of groups is not different from one group to another."  A direct analogy would be to say the language of sets is not different from one set to other.  Just as: the language of group theory is not different from one model of group theory to another.  Like, if it said $\forall x \forall y\in x \forall z\in x: yz=zy$, where $x$ meant a group, then we'd have a statement (a false one).

Comment: Don't be confused by a technical jargon. Theory just means a collection of axioms. *Any* axioms. Sometimes a theory would mean a consistent set of axioms (or one which we haven't found to be inconsistent yet), but it is still just a set of axioms.

Comment: I don't think it's just jargon.  The axioms of arithmetic are about natural numbers.  It seems significant whether the axioms of group theory are about groups or about elements of those groups.  Many of the most consequential paradoxes have resulted from the mere idea of containment.  Consider Tarsky's approach in assigning subscripts to differentiate different Truths, according to how many levels of quotations they reside in (to put it one way).  This makes all the difference in something like Russell's paradox too.

Comment: (1) Group axioms are axioms which describe the elements of a structure in the language of groups. **ALL** first-order axioms are axioms about elements of the model, rather than the models themselves. (2) The fact that axioms have an intended interpretation doesn't mean that is all they have, the field axioms might as well be given to model $\Bbb R$, but they certainly have other - significantly different - models. (3) The Russell paradox can be extended to every language with a binary relation $E$. There is no $x$ such that $y\mathrel{E}x\leftrightarrow y\not\mathrel{E}y$.

Comment: Okay then, so one last question: in the language of set theory, the sets are technically the elements then, yes?  ...I did learn this years ago, but went a different direction - sorry if I'm being annoying.

Comment: Yes, and no. In a model of set theory the elements of the universe are sets; the language of set theory is just a language with a single binary relation. It has no elements or so on. The language of $\leq$ and the language of $\in$ are the same language really (I mean, we use different symbols, but both languages have just one binary relation symbol). The axioms of set theory are written so that the elements of the universe are *intended* to be sets, yes.

Comment: Right, yes I recall that now.  I appreciate the help, it's coming back to me and I think I can work out the rest with some books I have.  The students don't need to know all this of course, but I'd feel like a fraud if I didn't either.

Answer (score 3):

There's a big difference between:

1. a liar sentence
2. the continuum hypthesis (i.e. the sentence "the continuum hypothesis is true")

The continuum hypothesis *is* a statement, and a perfectly good statement at that. Its kind of like the statement "for all $x$ and $y$, we have $xy=yx$" in group theory. The axioms of group theory cannot prove this statement (because not every group is Abelian) nor can they refute it (because some groups are Abelian), nonetheless it is a perfectly good statement in the language of group theory. Similarly, the usual axioms of set theory (called $\mathrm{ZFC}$) neither prove the continuum hypothesis nor refute it, which is equivalent to saying that the continuum hypothesis is true in some models of $\mathrm{ZFC}$ and false in others. But that doesn't mean its an ill-formed statement, just the like inability to prove or refute "for all $x$ and $y$, we have $xy=yx$" does not make this an ill-formed statement of group theory. For this reasons, I don't think the continuum hypothesis really belongs in a class about paradox. Strictly speaking, there's nothing paradoxical about the continuum hypothesis; its just surprising that such a natural-sounding statement is independent of the usual axioms of set theory.

The concept of a liar sentence, on the other hand, is very different. Liar sentences are amazing because if they're true then they're false, and if they're false then they're true. This means that the English language can express sentences that cannot be assigned a classical truthvale (i.e. $\mathbf{true}$ or $\mathbf{false}$) *even in principle.* A consequence of this is that formal languages must be carefully designed so that they cannot express liar sentences, otherwise thins tend to [explode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) the moment you try to assigned truthvalues to the sentences in a consistent way. That is surely surprising and paradoxical.

Comment: I see what you mean about the difference between the liar paradox and the continuum hypothesis.  I'm not sure though that we've nailed down exactly what a "paradox" is though.  The concept that "This sentence is false" is true iff it's false is really not that deep.  In a class, it would take like 2 minutes for that concept to sink in.  For this reason, I like the fact that you guys have explained why it doesn't count as a statement, because it's just too cheap.  A true paradox should be really (like in Quine) something forcing us to reject a fully assimilated belief.